# How to get current import paths in Python?

Tags: python, import, importerror

I get an `ImportError` exception somewhere in the code, but the same module can be imported safely at startup of the application. I'm curious to see which paths Python looks for modules to import, so that I can trace why this problem occurs. I found this:

`print sys.path`

Is this the list of ALL paths that system looks when tries to import a module?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The path locations that python checks by default can be inspected by checking [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.path#sys.path).

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Comment: Is this the list of ALL paths that system looks when tries to import a module?

Comment: Yes, it is. More details in Python Standard Library Modules documentation at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: But how to use with __import__?

Answer (score 13):

If you want a bit better formatting:

```
import sys

from pprint import pprint

pprint(sys.path)
```

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are **almost** correct

Python 3:

```
import sys
import_paths = sys.path
```

In Python 2.7:

```
import sys
import os
import copy
import_paths = copy.copy(sys.path)
if '__file__' in vars(): import_paths.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__,'..')))
```

In both versions the main file (i.e. `__name__ == '__main'` is `True`) automatically adds its own directory to sys.path. **However** Python 3 only imports modules from `sys.path`. Python 2.7 imports modules from both `sys.path` AND from the directory of the current file. This is relevant when you have a file structure like:

```
|-- start.py
|-- first_import
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- second_import.py
```

with contents
start.py:
`import first_import`
__init__.py:
`import second_import.py`

In Python 3 directly running __init__.py will work, but when you run start.py, __init__.py wont be able to `import second_import.py` because it wont be in `sys.path`.

In Python 2.7 when you run start.py, __init__.py will be able to `import second_import.py` even though its not in `sys.path` since it is in the same folder as it.

I cant think of a way to **perfectly** duplicate Python 2.7's behavior in Python 3 unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

`Sys.path` is a list of all the paths Python looks through when finding imports. If you want to add another path to a directory containing one or more python files, you can use:   `sys.path.append('path/to/directory')`.