# Multiversion of pythons on mac

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

Firstly, I'm aware several questions and answers about the similar problem on stackexchange already; and I just want to get a more consistent understanding of my current situation.

When I checked

```
which -a python
```

I obtained the following information:

```
/Users/yangtong/anaconda2/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

which were installed by different ways at different time I completely forgot... I know this is stupid and crazy...

Now my questions are:

1. which pythons listed above are system-bundled, and I should leave them alone? And which ones, e.g. the one in anaconda, can be safely uninstalled?
2. I installed some external packages, probably, for each of them, so is there any way I can view all installed packages for each of these 4 pythons  separately?
3. Can I remove some of them safely and effectively? I wouldn't expect there is any way I can move installed packages of all different pythons into the one I want to keep, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) The system-bundled one is : /usr/bin/python

(2) If pip is install on each version of Python, you can do (for example) :

```
/Users/yangtong/anaconda2/bin/python pip freeze
```

or (for /usr/bin/python)

```
/usr/bin/python
```

then

```
help("modules")
```

(3) You can still remove them, but I highly recommend you to create only virtual environment from now :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But why removing them is always not recommended??

Comment: Hello again! You can find the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117945/too-many-different-python-versions-on-my-system-and-causing-problems?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: For the Andoconda installed version you can type 'conda list' to get a list of modules installed in that environment.

Comment: Anaconda is very nice in that it makes it easy to create virtual environments.  Virtual environments enabled me to run both python 2.13 and python 3.6 on my Mac.

Comment: @jmh Conda is the one I want to keep besides the system-bundled one, since I just noticed most of previous packages were integrated by Conda. Thx!!

Comment: @MichaelCara Yeah I already knew the answer in that link. Just wondering, what about the one in "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python"? You said the system-bundled one is "/usr/bin/python", so this "Frameworks" has nothing to do with my system and can be safely removed, right?

Comment: I am not sure. If you look at that link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844746/how-to-uninstall-all-python-versions-and-use-the-default-system-version-of-os-x it says that one of those is a symlink to the other. Can't be sure exaclty which one it is because it depends of your os version.