# How to build a C file generated by Cython that uses opencv in Anaconda?

Tags: python, opencv, gcc, cython, anaconda

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, along with Anaconda Python 3
After writing a code in Python, to make it executable, (not using the #/usr/bin/python trick), I attempted to use Cython. It worked perfectly fine on my previous installation of Ubuntu with the default Python (not Anaconda). The commands I am using are (suppose file name:test.pyx, user name: user)

```
cython --embed test.pyx    #this generates a test.c
gcc -I /home/rsnk96/anaconda3/envs/py35/include/python3.5m -L /home/user/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib -o test test.c -lpython3.5m `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

The above command works perfectly alright with Anaconda python so long as it does not have any openCV command. However, when I import cv2, then it compiles, but executing it causes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.pyx", line 1, in init test (test.c:799)
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I have opencv installed on anaconda python, and the same test.pyx works perfectly fine on executing it using python

Comment: Is there some difference in [`sys.path`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751292/how-to-get-current-import-paths-in-python) between the two invocations?

Comment: Yes there is. Anaconda Python: Points to files and folders inside /home/user/anaconda3/. Normal Python: Points to files and directories in /usr/lib. 
Note: Cython was installed using conda