# Can't import lxml to python on MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

Python newbie here.

I'm trying to do a scraper in Python3, but I'm having problems importing `lxml` on my Sierra 10.12. 
Here's the process and additional info:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.1

$ pip3 install lxml
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

$ python3
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015, 21:12:44) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lxml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'lxml'
>>>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any other way to install a module?

I noticed that `lxml` seems to be installed on python `3.6` folder, even though my python3 version is `3.5.1`, is that what's wrong?

EDIT: I tried the same thing with python `2.7` and got the same result.

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10

$ pip install lxml
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

$ python2.7
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15)  
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lxml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'lxml'
>>>
```

Comment: looks like your pip is installing it for 3.6, not 3.5 (which is the version you are using). Could be that you have 2 different instances of python installed?

Comment: @RNar Maybe. If I type python and press tab, I see versions 2.6, 2.7, 3, 3.5 and 3.5m installed. I don't know where that version 3.6 is coming from.

Comment: @RNar I updated my answer. I tried the same thing with Python 2.7 and got the same results, even though pip is installing at the right directory.

Comment: can you double check your [`path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751292/how-to-get-current-import-paths-in-python) and make sure that the package path is in there?

Comment: Given that `python3` runs 3.5, `python3 -m pip install lxml` should install lxml in the 3.5 site-packages.  I have no idea about 2.7.

Comment: That did it for python 3.5 @TerryJanReedy, thank you!

Comment: @RNar here is the result of my path: ['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages']

Comment: The command that @TerryJanReedy will work for any instance of python (ie, you should be able to also then do `python2 -m pip install lxml`)

Comment: @RNar When I tried `python2.7 -m pip install lxml` I got this error `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named pip`

Comment: You could try `python2.7 -m ensurepip` to install pip with that python install.  But since that appears to be Apple's system python, that it uses for its scripts, you are better not to touch it.  I believe you can install current 2.7.14 into `Library` (instead of `System/Library` so that it does not conflict with the system install, but not having a Mac, I do not know the details.