# Problem with install.bash file on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, bash, installation, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to install a software called labelprinting which lets you print information on sticky labels.

The software functions perfectly on one computer, and my objective is to transfer the software to the other computer and run the label printing software by a third party and I have all the required files to install it.

Up until now, I've followed all the instructions outlined in the `readme.md` file. In my brief research on the installation process, I gathered that I need to run the `install.bash` script (unless I'm mistaken). I'm trying to execute the `install.bash` code on my Linux terminal. Here are the steps I've taken:

```bash
thal@thal-11T30037GE:/opt/usr/thal_labelprinting/doc$ sudo chmod +x install.bash
thal@thal-11T30037GE:/opt/usr/thal_labelprinting/doc$ sudo ./install.bash install
```

... and it gave me the following output with errors:

```
Creating virtual python environment
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  grub-pc-bin
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  virtualenv
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,982 B of archives.
After this operation, 13.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar/universe amd64 virtualenv all 20.19.0+ds-1 [1,982 B]
Fetched 1,982 B in 1s (1,355 B/s)      
Selecting previously unselected package virtualenv.
(Reading database ... 218593 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../virtualenv_20.19.0+ds-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking virtualenv (20.19.0+ds-1) ...
Setting up thal-labelprinting (1.1.0) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/usr/thal_labelprinting/bin/update.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Config import LabelsConfig, PrinterConfig
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Config'
dpkg: error processing package thal-labelprinting (--configure):
 installed thal-labelprinting package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up virtualenv (20.19.0+ds-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 thal-labelprinting
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ERROR!
```

It seems like there are issues with missing modules and package configurations. I suspect the `Config` module might be improperly configured or missing.

Here's a snippet from my `install.bash` script where it sets up the environment:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 install"
        exit 2
fi

function run()  {
local cmd=$1
echo $cmd
$cmd >> /dev/null 2>&1 || {
        echo "ERROR!"
        exit 1
        }
}

function check() {
        test $? -eq "0" || {
                echo "ERROR!"
                exit 1
        }
}

uid=`id -u`
test $uid -eq "0" || {
        echo "Must be root!"
        exit 1
}

echo ""
echo "Creating virtual python environment"
apt-get install -y virtualenv
check
run "mkdir -p /opt/usr/virtualenv"
run "virtualenv -p python3 /opt/usr/virtualenv/labelprinting"
#run "rm /opt/usr/virtualenv/lion/lib/python3.6/no-global-site-packages.txt"

echo ""
echo "Installing python packages"
run "/opt/usr/virtualenv/lion/bin/pip install wxPython==4.0.6"
run "/opt/usr/virtualenv/lion/bin/pip install elaphe3==0.2.0"
run "/opt/usr/virtualenv/lion/bin/pip install reportlab==3.5.23"

echo "Creating labelprinting logrotate configuration"
echo "/var/log/labelprinting/*/*.log {
        rotate 31
        compress
        missingok
        maxsize=10M
        daily
        notifempty
        copytruncate
}" > /etc/logrotate.d/labelprinting
check

echo "#PDF Cleanup Cronjob" >> /etc/crontab
echo "0 */4 * * * root find /data/labelprinting/ -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;" >> /etc/crontab
echo "" >> /etc/crontab


echo ""
echo "Finished successfully!"
exit 0
```

After installing `install.bash` running it on terminal

Based on the output you provided, there are two distinct errors:

The first error is related to the Python script `/opt/usr/thal_labelprinting/bin/update.py` which is encountering a `ModuleNotFoundError`. It's unable to find a module named `Config`. This suggests that there might be a missing or improperly configured dependency.

Following is the `update.py` file.
The `update.py` file is in the `bin` directory and the `Config.py` (error refrence) is in the same same directory but in the `lib` folder.

```py
#!/opt/usr/labelprinting/bin/python
import sys, os
import logging
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_AT.UTF-8')

from Config import LabelsConfig, PrinterConfig
from settings import PATH_LABELS_CONFIG_FILE, PATH_PRINTER_CONFIG_FILE

log = logging.getLogger("update")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    l = LabelsConfig(PATH_LABELS_CONFIG_FILE)
    p = PrinterConfig(PATH_PRINTER_CONFIG_FILE)
    l.load()
    p.load()

    if l.data['version'] == 1:
        log.info("updating label config file from version 1 to version 2")
        for label in l.data['data']:
            label['use_current_position'] = False
            label['current_col'] = 0
            label['current_row'] = 0
        l.data['version'] = 2
        l.save()

    if p.data['version'] == 1:
        log.info("updating printer config file from version 1 to version 2")
        for printer in p.data['data']:
            del printer['use_current_position']
            del printer['current_col']
            del printer['current_row']
        p.data['version'] = 2
        p.save()

    log.info("config update successfull")
    sys.exit(0)
```

This is the project root example.

I created the project root (?) just for example - I don't know if it helps.

Project Root

```
├── bin
│ ├── config.py
│ ├── main.py
│ └── update.py
├── doc
│ └── install.bash
├── lib
│ ├── Config.py
│ ├── ConfigGui.py
│ ├── Datamatrix.py
│ ├── Gui.py
│ ├── Labels.py
│ ├── Parser.py
│ ├── Pdf.py
│ ├── Printer.py
│ ├── Printout.py
│ └── setting.py
```

I changed the `update.py` code and changed `Config` to `config` but I believe it wants to import `Config` - which is in `lib` according to my understanding - but unable to locate it.

I also tried giving `lib.Config` but it did not work.

I tried various other things I might not be able to remember; I am in this rabbithole and am unable to figure out now.

Comment: Please follow the directions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751292/how-to-get-current-import-paths-in-python and add the import paths for `/opt/usr/labelprinting/bin/python` to your post.

Comment: Both of these scripts have very basic beginner errors which should probably be fixed. The immediate solution to your acute problem is probably something like `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/lib` but these scripts should probably be reviewed, or even rewritten from scratch for the Bash script in particular.